# asp.net vb debugging suddenly stops without code running

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-express

My asp.net Web application has stopped debugging correctly. When I try to debug (using any browser) nothing happens the browser after the “*connecting to localhost*”  no code is running from the master page or default.aspx. 
From the tracelogfiles I'm seeing a ***503 eventdata***.
Why is this happening and how do I resolve this issue?

***Note:*** If  I create a sample project everything is working perfect.